# How to reassign a variable inside a forloop and use it outside a for loop in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a xml looks like this

```
<component name="main">
    <component name="sub">
        <component name="a">
             <issues>
                <warning> </warning>
             </issues>
        </component>
        <component name="b">
             <issues>
                 <warning> </warning>
             </issues>
        </component>
        <component name="c">
           <issues>
              <error> </error>
           </issues>
        </component>
     </component>
 </component>
```

I want the output to look like below

```
"main": [
    {
        composite:"sub"
        result: "failure"
    }
]
```

Result can have 3 values. Which are listed below
Success: No error no warning
Failure: more than zero errors
Unstable: zero errors more than zero warnings

Result should be based on sub components result.The  In the above example "sub" has the result failure because one of its sub component c has error tag.

My code looks like below. Its not giving me the desired result. Please help me out

```
    <xsl:param name="error">0</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="warning">0</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="Success">0</xsl:param>
<xsl:for-each select="./components/components">     
<xsl:if test="./issues/error">        
<xsl:param name="error" select="'1'" />     
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test= "./issues/warning">   
<xsl:param name="warning" select="'1'" />       
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test= "not(./issues/warning) and not(./issues/error)">  
<xsl:param name="Success" select="'1'" />       
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each> 
<xsl:if test= "$error = '1'">
"result":"Failure"
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$error !='1' and $warning = '1'"> 
"result":"Unstable"
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$error !='1' and $warning != '1' and $warning = '1'"> 
"result":"Success"
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of variables:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./components">
  <xsl:text>"result":</xsl:text>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="count(./components/issues/error) &gt; 1">
      <xsl:text>"Failure"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="count(./components/issues/warning) &gt; 1">
      <xsl:text>"Unstable"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>"Success"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```